# Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in

Tags: php, xml, magento

I would like to ask for some assistance with my query please.

I've created a CMS page and would like to show products from a specific category in a list. So  I created a module and pasted the complete code from catalog/product/list.phtml in order to see if it would work out...

Unfortunately I got this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/design/frontend/bootstrapped/default/template/cmsproducts/index.phtml on line 23`

Here's the code from list.phtml

```
<?php echo get_class($this);
/**
 * Magento responsive theme
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     bootstrapped_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magenthon (http://magenthon.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * @author      Vedran Subotic <vedran@magenthon.com>
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div class="alert fade in">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
  <?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list unstyled row-fluid" id="products-list">
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?> row-fluid">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <div class="span4"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(225); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a></div>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="thumbnail data">
                    <div class="caption">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <span class="pull-right">
                            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </span>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="add-to-links unstyled">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist label label-info"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare label label-info"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li><hr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <ul class="products-grid unstyled thumbnails row-fluid">
            <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(225); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <p class="add-to-links unstyled">
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare label label-info pull-right"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist label label-info"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php
        /* @var $toolbar Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar */
        // get toolbars limits - overrides default pager limit
        $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getAvailableLimit();

        /* @var $pager Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager */
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'bootstrapped.standalone.pager');

        // set limit - uses category's instead of default pager's (10-20-50)
        $pager->setAvailableLimit($toolbar);
        // need to set collection
        $pager->setCollection($_productCollection);
        //set custom template
        $pager->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/pager.phtml');
        echo $pager->toHtml();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And for my CMS block:

```
{{block type="core/template" category_id="41" template="cmsproducts/index.phtml"}}
```

indexController.php for my custom module:

```
<?php
class Thaneuk_Cmsproducts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {  
    }
}
```

I've searched around for ways to add products from a category to a CMS page but each method results in an error or the products not showing.

Can anyone help or refer me to a step by step guide that works?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$_productCollection` is not an object, meaning that `$this->getLoadedProductCollection()` returns `null` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix to make it not throw the error would be

```
<?php if(is_object($_productCollection) && !$_productCollection->count()): ?>
```

But you still need to figure out the flaw in your code as to why `$_productCollection` is not getting loaded.

Comment: It's very puzzling as I've copied the code from list.phtml which loads in the main site but not when I use it as the template for my module in the CMS page...

Comment: Yes the error is no longer tere with your code and I can see the block class on the page echo get_class($this); but no products

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!!

```
<?php 
$category_id = "43"; // category_id for "Featured Products"
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description'), 'inner')
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id));
?>
<?php if($_productCollection->count()): ?>
      <div class="featured">
      <br />
      <ul id="featured-product-list">
        <div class="block-title">
      <h3><span><?php echo $this->__('FEATURED PRODUCT'); ?></span></h3>
    </div>
       <?php 
       $products = array();
       foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) { 
        ?>
        <li class="featured-product">
          <!--<h6>Price <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice());; ?></h6>-->
          <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
            <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(225, 200); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
          </a>
        </li>
       <strong><a class="view-item-button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Order'); ?> <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?><?php echo $this->__('&#8482;'); ?></a></strong>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <p>
            <?php echo $_product->_data['short_description']; ?>
        </p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>  
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
</div>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @Gershon Herczeg Although^ the above code means I have to create a template file for every product that i wish to show inside a CMS Page!

Comment: @Gershon Herczeg I've tried removing the category id from the template file and specify it in the block code but it loads every product from every category... I'll keep tweaking till I get it right

Answer (score -1):

same error was occurs to me. I'm using magento 1.9.1 at XAMPP server. 
I only reflushed all magento indexes and all works fine.

go to system/Index Management
select all options and execute "reindex data" Action